# Non-static method Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart::add() should not be called statically

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I downloaded the following library for laravel 8 shoppingcart https://github.com/hardevine/LaravelShoppingcart
my composer.json

```
    "require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "hardevine/shoppingcart": "^2.9",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
}
```

my shoppingcartController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart;
use App\Models\Products;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ShoppingcartController extends Controller
{
    public function add(){
    $product=Products::find(request('id'));

   Cart::add($product->id, $product->product_name, 1, $product->price);
   return redirect()->route('shoppingCart')
   ->with('message_type','success')
   ->with('message','Ürün sepete eklendi.');

}}
```

*I save and refresh the page I get an error* -->Non-static method Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart::add() should not be called statically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config/App Add a new line to the providers array:

```
Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\ShoppingcartServiceProvider::class
```

And optionally add a new line to the aliases array:

```
'Cart' => Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::class,
```

my shoppingcartController :

```
use Cart;
```

It happened when I used these commands.

Comment: or just  " use  Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart  "  enough to use